# Comparing each items to remaining items of a list

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, iteration

I am trying to compare each table column with other table's column one by one.

Here is the scenerio

**I have three tables like this**

and I am getting their information like this as List of TableRow

```
TableRow(students,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,200,name)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,100,address)

TableRow(department,INT,10,id)
TableRow(department,VARCHAR,100,department_name)

TableRow(teacher,INT,10,id)
TableRow(teacher,INT,10,suvject)
```

**suppose I want to compare each row to remaining rows of other tables like this ->**

```
TableRow(students,INT,10,id) - TableRow(department,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,INT,10,id) - TableRow(department,VARCHAR,100,department_name)
TableRow(students,INT,10,id) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,INT,10,id) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,suvject)

TableRow(students,VARCHAR,200,name) - TableRow(department,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,200,name) - TableRow(department,VARCHAR,100,department_name)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,200,name) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,200,name) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,suvject)

TableRow(students,VARCHAR,100,address) - TableRow(department,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,100,address) - TableRow(department,VARCHAR,100,department_name)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,100,address) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,id)
TableRow(students,VARCHAR,100,address) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,suvject)

TableRow(department,INT,10,id) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,id)
TableRow(department,INT,10,id) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,subject)

TableRow(department,VARCHAR,100,department_name) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,id)
TableRow(department,VARCHAR,100,department_name) - TableRow(teacher,INT,10,subject)
```

Therefore I am comparing each tables column to other table's column like above..

I am using code like this to compare it, which works but  is there any better approach for doing this ? A good functional way of writing it ?

```
 val stack = mutable.Stack[TableRow]().pushAll(tableRows)
    val arrayList = new util.ArrayList[JoinInfo]()

    while (stack.nonEmpty) {
      val currentRow = stack.pop()
      stack.foreach(targetRow => {
        if (!(targetRow.tableName.equals(currentRow.tableName) && targetRow.schema.equals(currentRow.schema))) { //not comparing with current table's column with its other column.
          arrayList.add(compareColumns(currentRow, targetRow))
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: Also, please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try asking this on Code Review

Comment: hi @user ,I didnt understand your logic, how it will compare currentRow to TargetRow for each and every entries ?

Comment: @user I think you didint get my question properly. It is not about removing duplicates , Its about comparing each item of a list to the remaining, condition being it should not consider comparing if the present row's table and schema name matches the other Row.

Comment: @user well, thats not the case , pls look at my second block ,where I explained what is actually expected to happen, then you will understand

Comment: @user no, you got the question wrong :D 
Here the question is not about filtering out anything, its about comparing elements when other elements 

List a = (1 2 3 4)

1->2 || 
1->3 ||
1->4 ||

2->3 ||
2->4 ||

3->4 ||

Comment: @user okey, I am not aware of code review community, is it part of this StackExchange ?

Comment: Yes. Here's the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also, I think you want something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bwOqYpe0RMCjUdIWdQg26g), with `yield` in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this :

```
(tableRows zip tableRows).filter {
  case(currentRow, targetRow) => !(targetRow.tableName.equals(currentRow.tableName) && targetRow.schema.equals(currentRow.schema))
}
```

So, pretty the same thing except it used the zip function to avoid manually writing the double loop.

Comment: not sure how I can use it with my code. can you please elaborate ?